# Duplicate values in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting duplicate values in JSON. I want to replace the previous value with new a value.

```
var obj = {};
obj.Product_Id = product_id;
obj.Qty = j;
var arr = [];
arr.push(obj);
var json = JSON.stringify(arr);
```

output is [{"Product_id":1,"Qty":1},{"Product_id":2,"Qty":1},{"Product_id":1,"Qty":2}]

i want this to be [{"Product_id":1,"Qty":2},{"Product_id":2,"Qty":1}]

If key repeat its value it should replace previous one not add the duplicate value

Comment: could you please be more precise?

Comment: var obj={};  
obj.Product_Id =product_id;
obj.Qty =j;

arr.push(obj);

var json = JSON.stringify(arr);

Comment: var arr = []; this is an empty array

Comment: that's not what he meant by "more precise" please post the resulting json as well.

Comment: So then there is no duplicate value in your array, it contains only the `obj`.

Comment: It's still not clear what the problem is. Please provide a minimal but complete example, including input, the output you get and the expected output you want. Guessing is just a waste of our and your time!

Comment: Rewrite your question and show relevant code.

Comment: question is very vague, too much editing going on by 3rd persons, should get closed in its current form.

Comment: output is [{"Product_id":1,"Qty":1},{"Product_id":2,"Qty":1},{"Product_id":1,"Qty":2}] i want this to be                [{"Product_id":1,"Qty":2},{"Product_id":2,"Qty":1}] product_id 1 comes to time i want this to be last one

Comment: This needs to be closed so the OP can get their thoughts and code together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to maintain a unique key, you must remove any existing element with this key and then add the new object

```
var arr = ...;
var newObj = ...;
arr = arr.filter(function(el) { return el.Product_id != newObj.Product_id; });
arr.push(newObj);
```

If you want to maintain the order and know an element with this key exists already, you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var arr = ...;
var newObj = ...;
arr = arr.map(function(el) {
    if (el.Product_id != newObj.Product_id)
        return el;

    return newObj;
});
```

For a reference on Array methods and properties, you can look at [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).